# Best way to check for duplicates in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure what is the best way to tackle this problem. I have a lot of calculations in my workbook and I'm trying to make it as fast and light as possible.

So my question is if I have five columns with in total 200 values, what is the best way to look for duplicates? I really don't want to make a `=countif` for every cell and everywhere I read people are saying that VBA is not the best way to do it, so what would you recommend? I need to use the result in VBA so I was wondering if the color set could be a solution because that appear to be light and fast.

Comment: I just need to know where they are located so I can pop up a userform so it can be change manually

Comment: If you are going to use it in vba then use vba to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the values in an array and check the array for duplicates.

You can then create a result() array with unique values, or do anything you like, and then post the resulting array in your sheet.

This is way more efficient than manipulating cells in your sheet, by orders of magnitude.

Comment: that sounds like a good solution. Thanks Álvaro

Comment: Nice this solution just fixed another problem I had with a large userlist :)

Comment: Glad to know this helped! I had a similar problem myself in the recent past, where I was manipulating 300k+ rows of a column. Mixed with a not-so-great computer, I was having performance issues on Excel as well. Storing everything in an array and pasting the result in the sheet afterwards solved it for me :)